# Orderby within a foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

I have this simple foreach and for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to orderby file within the foreach. Any assistance would be appreciated. Yes I have been Googling to figure it out but nothing has worked so far.

```
foreach (string file in CombFiles)
            {
                 string ServiceLitID = @"<a href=" + Q + "../LitFolder/" + file + "</a><br>";
                 cmbsHtmlfile.WriteLine(ServiceLitID);
            }
```

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: `foreach (string file in CombFiles.OrderBy(....))` ?

Comment: What are you trying to sort "within" the foreach? Do you mean sorting the list that you will then iterate over? Because that's not _within_ the foreach, that's _before_ it.

Comment: This was me trying to edit someone else's code. Upon scouring the code a little further, CombFiles is an ArrayList and is already sorting. CombFiles contains strings that the previous developer has built. The end user wanted to sort by a portion of that string. In the codes current state, it cannot be done without some rewriting. Thank you